# Change Hover dropdown function to click function

Tags: javascript, css

Im new to CSS and JS. Im trying to make my fixed menu open on click rather than hover please can someone have a look at my CSS and Javacript and tell me where i'm going wrong?

I Have tried to have a play about as much as i can but its got me stumped, so any help would be appreciated!

```
.navigation { float: left; }
    nav ul ul {
display: none;
        position: fixed;
}


nav ul li:click > ul {
    display: block;
}
nav ul {
background: #efefef; 
background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
padding: 0 20px;
border-radius: 10px;  
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: block;
}
nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}
nav ul li {
float: left;
}
nav ul li:hover {
    background: #4b545f;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
}
    nav ul li:hover a {
        color: #eee;
    }

nav ul li a {
    display: block; padding: 45px 40px;
    color: #757575; text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.5em
m
}
nav ul ul {
background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
nav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
    position: relative;
}
    nav ul ul li a {
        padding: 15px 40px;
        color: #fff;
    }   
        nav ul ul li a:hover {
            background: #4b545f;
        }
nav ul ul ul {
position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}
```

And my basic javascript is :

```
$('#menu > li').click(function() {
      $( this ).addClass( "active" ).siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: Can you provide the html please

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand your menu structure without a html file but i think i know the problem

```
nav ul li:click > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

should be .active instead of :click since you are adding the class .active in your js

```
nav ul li.active > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou thats part solved my issue :)....now the menu just disappears when i release the mouse click ?

Comment: provide your html please

Comment: Please see above, ive just added it for you. thankyou

Comment: no, you don't have a remove class function.
read https://api.jquery.com/ for more info

Answer (score 0):

Here is my HTML:

```
<nav style="width: 100%" id="nav">
            <ul>
               <img style="padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 2px" src="file:///C:/Users/danr/Desktop/Jsp2/images/menu-images/Langlogomini.png" id="logo" /> 

                <li><a href="#"> Menu <img src="file:///C:/Users/danr/Desktop/images/Down-Arrow.png"> </a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><img style="padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 10px;" src="http://go.jsp.co.uk/images/navbar/headmini.png">Head Safety</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img style="padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 10px;" src="http://go.jsp.co.uk/images/navbar/eyemini.png">Eye Safety</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img style="padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 10px;" src="http://go.jsp.co.uk/images/navbar/fullhalf.png">Face Masks</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img style="padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 10px;" src="http://go.jsp.co.uk/images/navbar/disposable.png">Disposable Masks</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#"><img style="padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 10px;" src="http://go.jsp.co.uk/images/navbar/hearing.png">Ear Safety</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#"><img style="padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 10px;" src="http://go.jsp.co.uk/images/navbar/contact.png">Contact</a></li>
                  </ul>                                      
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
 <style>
```